# Getting error when trying to integrate ansible with checkpoint Management server

Tags: ansible

I am trying to integrate Ansible with my Checkpoint Management Server. Ansible is running on ubuntu 18.04.2. PFB the error when i run ansible-playbook ansible-cp-test.yml

> PLAY [GW] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
>
> TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
>       ok: [127.0.0.1]
>
> TASK [login] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
>       fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/ankur/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1561225518.27-40894102526111/AnsiballZ_check_point_mgmt.py\", line 114, in \r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/home/ankur/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1561225518.27-40894102526111/AnsiballZ_check_point_mgmt.py\", line 106, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File \"/home/ankur/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1561225518.27-40894102526111/AnsiballZ_check_point_mgmt.py\", line 49, in invoke_module\r\n    imp.load_module('**main**', mod, module, MOD_DESC)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_check_point_mgmt_payload_lvOSrx/**main**.py\", line 8, in \r\nImportError: No module named cpapi\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
>
> PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
>       127.0.0.1                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

I am new to this so don't understand what this error means. Please help.

followed Ansible deployment guide available on checkmates

Comment: Hi Ankur, welcome to SO. In the future, you will want to provide enough context in your question to enable folks to come up to speed on what you are doing and how. Including the version of ansible, the version of python, and **for sure** include the playbook -- or in your case a pointer to the github project you were using. Read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page carefully to have a good experience here. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have failed to follow [the installation instructions](https://github.com/CheckPointSW/cpAnsible#installation-instructions) for the project you are using.

The error is caused by [a required python package](https://github.com/CheckPointSW/cpAnsible/blob/187aaf5450ed69b004b26f5f81ccb1b594337085/check_point_mgmt/check_point_mgmt.py#L8) used by their ansible module. Be aware that ansible requires that said python package be available in the python interpreter it uses when it connects, not the python that is hosting ansible on the control system. Usually that python is described by the `ansible_python_interpreter` fact, but the best outcome is to ensure the module is installed by using the [`pip:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/pip_module.html) module before invoking their `check_point_mgmt:` task

Comment: Thanks for the Reply Matthew. Python package is already copied to python2.7 folder and imported as well through python interpreter and didn't get any error.

Comment: That may very well be, but the error you posted shows that the ansible interpreter attempted to import that `cpapi` package and failed. So since it's running against your local machine, and whatever python you used to test it does have `cpapi`, then run ansible again with `-e ansible_python_interpreter=$(which python)` so that you and ansible will be on the same page about what "remote" python you want to use